# Selecting multiple items in AnyGantt

Tags: gantt-chart, anychart

Can I enable multiple selection in AnyGantt, either in the datagrid part or (preferably) in the chart part?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of September 2017, AnyGantt 7.14.3 provides only single mode selection for the purpose of showing extra information about selected item or a row in the datagrid.